# How to implement prerequisite table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys

I'm using Laravel and I've a table in database called 'course'. It has some fields like 'title', 'content' and etc...
And also I want a course has some prerequisites (other courses). How can I implement this? I can do this by self reference foreign key but in this way there will be just one prerequisite for a course.

Comment: I think your answer is in the title - create and implement a prerequisite table.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, you are right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Course can has many Prerequisites and one Prerequisite belongs to many Courses its an n:m relationship.

Create a pivot table `course_prerequisite` with the fields `id`, `course_id`, `prerequisite_id`.

To the Course Model add a `prerequisites()` method with `BelongsToMany` relationship like so:

```
prerequisites() : BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_prerequisite', 'course_id', 'prerequisite_id')
}
```

If you need a reverse relationship, add a `courses` method with `BelongsToMany`:

```
courses() : BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'course_prerequisite', 'prerequisite_id', 'course_id')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many passible ways to do this. I mention 2 ways to do this.

Method 1:

You can create your course table like this.

```
Create table courses(
id int(10) not null primary key,
title varchar(25),
content varchar(255)
);
```

and now create another table for prerequisites mapping.

```
create table prerequisites(
course_id int(10),
prerequisite_id int(10),
foreign key (course_id) references courses(id),
foreign key (prerequisite_id) references courses(id)
)
```

Method 2:

Another way of doing this is by adding new column in courses table for prerequisites courses. Although you can not add foreign key constraint in this way but you can manage that programatically.

```
Create table course(
id int(10) not null primary key,
prerequisites varchar(250),
title varchar(25),
content varchar(255)
)
```